# Frog identification - two different frogs seen in New Zealand

Tags: species-identification

Me and my friends saw these two frogs in man-made ponds in an area which is undergoing development for residential use. Anyone able to identify these beauties?

Also would be interested as to how these frogs got there, as the pond wouldn't have existed 2-3 years ago and there are none nearby.

Location these were found can be seen in the following link:
https://www.pic2map.com/yibrir.html

[image: Frog A][image: Frog B]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first frog(the green one) resemble 
**GREEN AND GOLDEN BELL FROG - *Litoria Aurea*** 
[image]

**Description of the frog -**

- Have golden-bronze colored spots
- Have a black line from the eye to the nostrils
- Found in northern Island

And coming to the second frog it resembles
 **Southern Bell Frog - *Litoria Raniformis***

[image: this one]

**Description of the frog - **

- Have a distinctive black line running through their back
- Found almost everywhere in new Zealand
- They have black-brown patches on their skin (can increase in blackness based on the surrounding environment)

---

Coming to your question , the golden bell frog seems to stay in small temporary water ponds even puddles

On the contrary the southern bell frog lives permanently in a pond so probably it lives somewhere nearby

That'll be it